# Learning Python: Is there a better way to write words + vars to file?

Tags: python

For example, the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

cliente = 'TESTE'
servidor_virtual = '10.2.192.115'
porta = '22'
conf = "# pool " + cliente + '\n' "virtual_server" + servidor_virtual + porta + '\n'    
f = open('cliente.conf', 'w')
f.write(conf)
f.close()
```

I'm beginning at Python and creating a model to write some confs to a file.
I just found this way, but i want to know if there another more elegant way to do this.
And i want to mix word with variables values too.

Comment: What's wrong with this?  It works great, doesn't it?

Comment: And you might really want to start using english in your code (except for strings). Usually nobody likes variable names etc which are not english (for example, I'm german and hate every developer who used german variables etc)

Comment: S.Lott, there is nothing wrong about this, and yes it worked well. I just want to make sure there's another way to do. Thanks for reply !

Comment: ThiefMaster, im starting to use english in my codes right now. Thanks for reply !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To process configuration files you should use the `ConfigParser` module. See [the ConfigParser docs](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html).

Comment: Sure i will read the ConfigParser docs. I saw some examples using this. Thanks for reply !

Comment: You're welcome. Note that if all you need is just to write a .conf file like the one you wrote, ConfigParser doesn't help you as the structure of the config file is fixed (.ini syntax). If the config file is for your own application, then ConfigParser is the best way to manage it.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible way to do this is to use lists and the string join function.

```
conf = ["# pool ", cliente, '\n', "virtual_server", servidor_virtual, porta, '\n']
f.write(''.join(conf))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this.

cliente.py

```
 cliente = 'TESTE'
 servidor_virtual = '10.2.192.115'
 porta = '22'
```

Actual Application.py

```
 conf= {}
 execfile( 'cliente.py', conf )
 # now conf['cliente'], conf['servidor_virtual'] and conf['porta'] are all set.
```

Comment: Yes, im trying to write/create conf. Thanks for reply !

Comment: @Graeme Perrow: Creating a conf file (especially by writing code) is a total waste of time.  Sure, it could be a use case, but it creates no value.  Creating a conf file manually and **using** the conf file is the more typical use case.

Comment: `import cliente as conf` seems nicer than execfile to me.

Comment: @Paul Hankin: did you post that as an answer?  Please do.  Let folks upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I might suggest is to use string formatting. I *think* it's generally faster than string concatenation, but can be more difficult to read. In your case,

```
conf = "# pool %s\nvirtual_server %s:%d\n" % (cliente,servidor_virtual,porta)
```

Note that I cleaned up the string a little - you have "virtual_server" followed by the IP address with no space or separator at all, and then the port is directly after *that* with no separator.

Other than that, what you have is fine.

Comment: Nice example, i will try this one adding some spaces.Thanks for reply !